# Does Flex dispatch an event when a popup is brought to the foreground?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

Is there an event dispatched when a modal is brought to the front in Flex? Basically there are two times when I would want to listen for this event:

- When the modal is first created (although in theory creationComplete / show / etc.. could suffice here)
- When the user brings a modal that is not in the front to the front by clicking on it.

In my case the popups I am working with are descendants of TitleWindow and listening for focusIn does not seem to work reliably.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up listening for "focusIn" and "focusOut". Flex Builder's intellisense doesn't offer these up as events you can listen for but it turns out that you can. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

Try listening to "addedPopUp" and "bringToFront" events of `PopUpManagerImpl.getInstance()`:

```
import mx.managers.PopUpManagerImpl;

PopUpManagerImpl.getInstance().addEventListener("addedPopUp", addedPopUpHandler);
PopUpManagerImpl.getInstance().addEventListener("bringToFront", bringToFrontHandler);

private function addedPopUpHandler(event:DynamicEvent):void
{
    trace("Added popup: " + event.window);
}

private function bringToFrontHandler(event:DynamicEvent):void
{
    trace("Front: " + event.popUp);
}
```

Comment: To add to this, I'm questioning *why* you need to listen for an event in the first place.  You're the one creating and controlling the popup; if you want an event to dispatch, I would just dispatch a custom event.

Comment: PopUpManagerImpl.getInstance() isn't an EventDispatcher, so I get errors when I try to call addEventListener on it.

Comment: @J_A_X -- The reason I want this is at any time the user may have multiple non-modal popups visible and I want to be notified when they bring one to the front.

Comment: Try `EventDispatcher(PopUpManagerImpl.getInstance()).addEventListener`? If no luck then `PopUpManagerImpl.getInstance()["addEventListener"]`.

Answer (score 2):

You can listen to Event.AddedToStage on your UIComponent(modal) for this.